# attach the document object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to attach the document object to move div inside another div, here is the script: http://jsfiddle.net/vhDpG/2/ i want to move the block "moveme" just inside the `#bee_div1` not inside the `#body` div, but the action - animate(), must be triggered everytime mousemoves inside the `#body`

thank you all for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/RBaXe/12

notice I am setting up bounds based on its parent container and not letting bee leave the bounds

I also added some borders, so that we could tell whether or not it was actually staying in the bounds we were setting

EDIT TOP AND LEFT BOUND
http://jsfiddle.net/RBaXe/12/

Comment: good, it is bounded to bottom, and right, what about left side and top

Comment: but it goes out of the div on the top and left side of it

Comment: thats fixed. check it out again

Answer (score 1):

check the bounds of the container and move div accordingly, something like this:

```
$("#body").mousemove(function(event) {
    var top = $('#bee_div1').offset().top;
    var bottom = $('#bee_div1').offset().top + $('#bee_div1').height() - $('#bee1').outerHeight();
    var left = $('#bee_div1').offset().left;
    var right = $('#bee_div1').offset().left + $('#bee_div1').width() - $('#bee1').outerWidth();

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    if( event.pageX > right) {
        x = right;       
    } else if( event.pageX < left) {
        x = left;      
    } else {
        x = event.pageX;   
    }

    if( event.pageY > bottom) {
        y = bottom;      
    } else if( event.pageY < top) {
        y = top;      
    } else {
        y = event.pageY;  
    }

    console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY, top, bottom, left, right);
   $("#bee1").stop().animate({left: x, top: y}, 100)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bsrykt/MvkZJ/